# FromRoute and FromQuery in the same model has different results between asp net core 2.2 and 3.0

Tags: model-binding, asp.net-core-3.0

I don't know if it's any different default configuration, but by creating an asp.net core 2.2 project and another asp.net core 3.0 project, I'm getting different results in model binding.

```
public class Dto
{
     public string Prop1 { get; set; }

     public string Prop2 { get; set; }      

     public string Prop3 { get; set; }                  

     public string Prop4 { get; set; }

}
```

```
[HttpGet("test/{prop1:alpha}/{prop2:alpha}")]
public ActionResult<Result> Test(Dto dto)
{
}
```

The above code works perfectly in asp.net core 2.2 when the url is called:

```
https://localhost:xxxx/test/aaa/bbb/?prop3=ccc&prop4=ddd
```

However, in asp.net core 3 the object is null.

if i use `[FromRoute]` it just gets the values of prop1 and prop2.

If I use `[FromQuery]` it just gets the values of prop3 and prop4.

How do I configure asp.net core 3 so that it get the values of the route and querystring like asp.net core 2.2 ?

Note that in asp.net core 2.2 I have not informed either `[FromRoute]` or `[FromQuery]` that seem to me mandatory now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In time, it is possible to have the same results using ApiController attribute, however, by setting the SuppressInferBindingSourcesForParameters property to true.

Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found that the problem refers to using the ApiExplorer attribute.

Without it, it works exactly as I would like.